# Regex for last words in string?

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string such as:

```
Woori Finance Holdings Co Ltd
Alliance One International Inc
```

And I want to remove things like Co, Company, International etc regardless of case, as long as they are at the end of a string.

```
re.compile(r'\b(Incorporated|Corporation|Company|Inc Common Stock|QQQ|ETF|PLC|SA|Inc|Corp|Ltd|LP|plc|Group|The|Co|International)$',
           flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

This regex manages to locate the last element of a string but how do I continue going until it hits a word that's not in the regex; ie, the above strings would result in:

```
Woori Finance Holdings
Alliance One
```

I also want to add that I wouldn't want to remove `Company` if it were at the start or middle of a string, only if it is part of the end of a string.

Comment: Try removing the `$`

Comment: @DroidX86 This then matches **Co**ca-**Co**la **Co** whereas I'd only want to match the final **Co**

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex to match 1+ to-be-removed words at the end:

```
(?:\s+(?:Incorporated|Corporation|Company|Inc Common Stock|QQQ|ETF|PLC|SA|Inc|Corp|Ltd|LP|plc|Group|The|Co|International))+\s*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UCvjJT/1)

For python use:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?:\s+(?:Incorporated|Corporation|Company|Inc Common Stock|QQQ|ETF|PLC|SA|Inc|Corp|Ltd|LP|plc|Group|The|Co|International))+\s*$', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

s = regex.sub('', s)
```

Comment: It definitely works, but were the extra processors needed? I'm asking cause one day I want to reach your level. These also worked although with 1 trailing space.`re.sub('(?i)(Incorporated|Corporation|Company|Inc Common Stock|QQQ|ETF|PLC|SA|Inc|Corp|Ltd|LP|plc|Group|The|Co|International)[\ ]*', '', s)` and `re.sub('(?i)(?:(Incorporated|Corporation|Company|Inc Common Stock|QQQ|ETF|PLC|SA|Inc|Corp|Ltd|LP|plc|Group|The|Co|International))[\ ]*', '', s)`

Comment: Two options that you're suggesting will leave a trailing space in original string. Moreover both of the regex you've suggested are going to be very slow as compared to the one I have posted. You can check **no of steps taken** in regex101 website and verify.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub` to replace last unnecessary characters:

```
import re

s1 = 'Woori Finance Holdings Co Ltd'
s2 = 'Alliance One International Inc'

pattern = re.compile(r'\b(Incorporated|Corporation|Company|Inc Common Stock|QQQ|ETF|PLC|SA|Inc|Corp|Co Ltd|Ltd|LP|plc|Group|The|Co|International)$', flags=re.IGNORECASE)

print(re.sub(pattern, '', s1))
# Woori Finance Holdings

print(re.sub(pattern, '', s2))
# Alliance One International
```

Note that I've also added `'Co Ltd'` as part of pattern to be matched.

Comment: If first input is `Woori Finance Holdings Corporation Ltd` then it won't work. You cannot have every combination of multiple to-be-removed words in your regex.